# Laravel 7 Makes 'Integer' Validation message appears when the input is null even though it is not required

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, validation

Laravel pops up the integer validation message when the input is null

**View**

```
   <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Sipërfaqja(Metra Katror)</label>
                            <input type="number" name="area" value="{{old('area')}}"
                                   class="form-control form-control-border @error('area') is-invalid @enderror "
                                   placeholder="220">

                            @if($errors->has('area'))
                                <div style="color: red">{{ $errors->first('area') }}</div>
                            @endif
  </div>
```

**Controller**

```
 $rules = [

'area' => 'integer',
];

$messages = array(

       'area.integer' => 'Area should be integer value',
);
```

I leave the input null, but this message appears in the frontend **Area should be integer value**.

Comment: then add the `nullable` rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as  in Laravel [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields):

> By default, Laravel includes the TrimStrings and
> ConvertEmptyStringsToNull middleware in your application's global
> middleware stack. These middleware are listed in the stack by the
> App\Http\Kernel class. Because of this, you will often need to mark
> your "optional" request fields as nullable if you do not want the
> validator to consider null values as invalid.

so, your code should look like:

```
$messages = array(

       'area.integer' => 'nullable|integer',
);
```